# I installed pycharm on my raspberry pi 3b+, How do you open pycharm after install?

Tags: pycharm, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, startup

I can't seem to find a way to open pycharm on my raspberry pi 3b+. I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjro_0_eWAI&ab_channel=Gam3T3cHElectronics. And I forgot to add it to desktop.

I have no experience with any linux like OS. So any help on this question is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that you first need to download a pycharm tar from its homepage. Then you need to look at where it gest downloaded on your pi. Then you can use the command "cd" followed by the name of the directory the tar is in. Then you type in ls. This will show you the contents of the current directory. Then you use cd and ls to find pycharm enter its bin and find a file called pycharm.sh . when you find this file you can use the command "./pycharm.sh" to activate pycharm. (Keep in mind pycharm does need an updated version of java to work. (That solved it for me after a lot of personal research)